# ASP.NET Core RC2 Migration - infinite page loading

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core-rc2

I am having a problem migrating my existing **ASP.NET Core RC1** (with angular2) application to RC2. The actual problem is kinda strange. I was able to fix all compiler errors and the iss-express is starting just fine. But then nothing happens. The browser displays the usual loading screen but there are no network requests visible in the developer tools.

My `Startup.cs` looks like that:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

        // Repositories
        services.AddScoped<IVendorRepository, VendorRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IAdjustmentRepository, AdjustmentRepository>();
        // Entityframework
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"])
        );

        services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
        });
    }
}
```

and my `Program.cs` looks like that:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Did anyone run into that same problem? If so, how did you guys fix it?
And could someone explain to me why the web.config file is now placed in the root of the project instead of in `wwwroot` folder?

Here is also the project.json as gist https://gist.github.com/SamiAl90/a39d5966d2ca5ffed9dfc87ed7479680

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this helpful to you? https://ievangelist.github.io/blog/migrating-to-rc2/

Comment: best way to migrate to rc2 is to create new project/solution then migrate and fix the code files to make sure nothing is left over from rc1 that does not belong. for example make sure to delete the web.config file from the wwwroot folder. also would be interested to see your project.json to make sure there are no mistakes there

Comment: I agree with Joe.  It's safest just to copy your code to a new RC2 project.  But if you don't want to do that, [here](https://ievangelist.github.io/blog/migrating-to-rc2/) is a migration guide that might help.  I found that even after a successful migration you still keep the old project properties from RC1.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the hints. I actually went through plenty migration tutorials. That way I solved the compiler errors. I think I will try migrating everything in a new project, step by step. I will also post my project.json in the OP for you guys. ty again

Comment: The code you showed works fine for me.

Comment: make sure you remove all breakpoints, the application could be hanging waiting for you to continue.

Comment: @svick as I said, there was no problem with the code it's the infinite loading.I made sure that there are non breakpoints left still the same problem. I guess I will just create a new project, copy and paste the things step by step to see when it will stop working. Ty all for the help.

Comment: Hey guys.. I solved it by uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio and everything it depends on. After that even the old project was working just fine. I guess something was wrong with the .NET Components